# Put webpage text into a textview (Android)

Tags: java, android, html

I want to put a text from a webpage to a textview on Android 3.0. I have this code:

```
public class Biografie extends Activity {
    private TextView outtext;
    private String HTML;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_biografie);

        outtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1); 

        try { 
        getHTML();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    outtext.setText("" + HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.biografie, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void getHTML() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 

    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://artistone.appone.nl/api/biografie.php?dataid=998"); //URL!
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + "\n";
            HTML = result;
        }

    }

}
```

My TextView returns "null" instead of the text from the page. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in regard.

Comment: do you get an exception from getHTML ? and what is the target device you are testing on ?

Comment: I Test on an Android 4.0.2 tablet

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line + "\n";
}
HTML = result;
```

and try this: 
`outtext.setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML));`

And instead of performing network action in main thread i will suggest you to do this in separate thread using `AsyncTask`

Comment: App crashed when I do this.

Comment: Inside while block of your getHtml() method

Comment: Get alot of errors, i think i put the code on the wrong place? Could you show the complete new code? Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`
That is because you are downloading network content on the Main Thread (Activity's Thread).

Instead you need to use a background thread to download that content, or use **AsynchTask**.

A simple code that should fix this issue:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                getHTML();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        outtext.setText("" + HTML);

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        outtext.setText(e.toString());

                    }
            }
        }
    };
thread.start(); // I forgot to start the thread. sorry !
```

Instead of :

```
    try { 
           getHTML();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }       
    outtext.setText("" + HTML);
```

Also take a look at this tutorial about android threads : [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Sorry I didn't start the thread ... please check the code now it should show something at any cost